# ReliableCollection reverse index

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, reliable-dictionary

I am in the process of building a StatefulService and I'd like to store the data in a reliable collection

My class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Value { get; set;}

   public int Count {get; set;}

   public string[] Metadata {get; set;}
}
```

I am storing it in the following dictionary:

```
IReliableDictionary<string, Item>
```

where the key is a string.

To speed queries I can use the indexing extensions: https://github.com/jessebenson/service-fabric-indexing

What I am not sure about is how to create indexes for the collection of **metadata** so that given a string I can have retrieve all the Item object that have that string as metadata.

So far the only idea I came up with has been to create a

```
IReliableDictionary<string,string[]>
```

where the key is the metadata and it returns an array of keys I can use to retrieve the Items from the first collection.

Any better ideas?

Comment: How are you using the collection of metadata?

Comment: @Train I use to store a set of strings, but what I am looking for is a way to have a IEnumerable<Item> FindItemsByMetadata(string metadataValue) function